# How to find our what (not how much) memory is installed on a Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I have remote access (including root access) to a Ubuntu 9 server, but can't inspect it physically or reboot it.

I want to find out the memory speed (and ideally maker and model) of the RAM installed in the server. I can install additional software if necessary. Is there a command line way of getting this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dmidecode is your best bet aside from opening the cover and looking.  Most computers (if you can access the cover with the cables in) don't have any problem running with the cover off briefly.

dmidecode needs to be run as root, and provides you an absurd level of detail about the hardware.  I strongly recommend looking at the output for the info you want.